# Async/Await Ignoring Return

Tags: javascript, twilio, twilio-api

I want to send different SMS to different people and each call to send the SMS should be synchronous, I implemented the async await for my function to work like this, but for some reason it's not working as expected.

Here's my code:

After query for qualified users,

```
if(userQualifies) {
   try{
      await insertIntoTable();
   } catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
   }
}

async function insertIntoTable(){
   try{
     await db.any(QUERY TO INSERT)
       .then(async function(idCreated){
          try{
             var params = {
                 'messagingServiceSid': 'XXXXXXXXXX',
                 'to': ['1' + phone],
                 'body': message,
              }
              await sendMessage(params);
          }catch(error){
             console.log(error);
          }
       })

   } catch(err){
       console.log(err);
   }
}

async function sendMessage(params) {
   console.log('Im on sendMessage');
    return client.messages.create(params)
        .then( msg => {
            console.log("SUCCESS:");
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("ERROR:");
        });
    console.log("message sent");
    return 'done';
}
```

when I run this, I get the log of `Im on sendMessage` after inserting into the table but it doesn's send the message, it's ignoring the return of the `sendMessage()` function and sends all of the messages at the end at the same time.

Am I missing something to make it send the message when it goes from `insertIntoTable()` to `sendMessage()`

Comment: Don't use `then` (and never pass `async` functions as callbacks to it) when you are using `async`/`await`.

Comment: The code is too opaque to understand. What does `db.any().then()` do? is the `.then` function being called with multiple `idCreated` values in quick succession, or just one?

Comment: I do'nt see any opportunity for more than one `sendMessage` call to happen at a time.

Comment: Btw you've got two `return` statements in `sendMessage` - everything after the first is dead code. You will only get `SUCCESS` or `ERROR`, the  `console.log("message sent");` can *never* happen.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what most of your code is doing, but here's the async pattern for waiting for one thing in an array to finish its async action before starting the next one:

```
async function sendMessage(params) {
   console.log('Im on sendMessage');
    return client.messages.create(params)
        .then( msg => {
            console.log("SUCCESS:");
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("ERROR:");
        });
}

const messages = [{
                 'messagingServiceSid': 'XXXXXXXXXX',
                 'to': ['1000000'],
                 'body': 'first message',
              },{
                 'messagingServiceSid': 'XXXXXXXXXX',
                 'to': ['2000000'],
                 'body': 'second message',
              },
              {
                 'messagingServiceSid': 'XXXXXXXXXX',
                 'to': ['3000000'],
                 'body': 'third message',
              }];

async function setMultipleMessages(messages) {
  for (let message of messages) {
    await sendMessage(message);
  }
}

setMultipleMessages(messages);
```